# std::ifstream throwing error in Xcode 5

Tags: c++, xcode, file, ifstream

I'm trying to read in some GLSL source from simple plain text files using the following.

I provide the sources to the constructor like so:

```
Shader *shader = new Shader("res/default.vert", "res/default.frag");
```

The constructor passes those paths on directly to my little OSUtils file that reads in plain text and returns std::string:

```
Shader::Shader(const std::string& vertPath, const std::string& fragPath)
{
  addVertexShader(vertPath);
  addFragmentShader(fragPath);
}

void Shader::addVertexShader(const std::string& path)
{
  try {
      const std::string shaderSrc = OSUtils::fileToBuffer(path);
      compileVertexShader(shaderSrc);
  } catch (int e) {
      std::cout << "Error no: " << e << std::endl;
      exit(1);
  }
}
```

The addFragmentShader function is nearly identical.

The fileToBuffer function is as such:

```
const std::string OSUtils::fileToBuffer(const std::string& path)
{
  std::cout << "Trying to load: " << path << std::endl;
  std::ifstream in(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  if (in)
  {
      std::string contents;
      in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
      contents.resize(in.tellg());
      in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
      in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());
      in.close();
      return(contents);
  }
  throw(errno);
}
```

This throws the error with Errno 2 (No file found) in the addVertexShader function. And here's the kicker. I have this EXACT code running in a different project. Most of this code was copypasta from that earlier project that compiles just fine.

I'm running both projects in Xcode 5. The files themselves (res/default.vert and res/default.frag) have been added to the target and are listed in the Compile Sources listing under the target's Build Phases tab. In other words, everything seems in order, but I can't figure out why it won't load the files in this project. Is there some mysterious Xcode setting I'm missing? I'd suspect the code if it wasn't 100% identical to the code in the working project. The other project also mimics the file structure with both the .vert and .frag files living in a res/ folder. The only difference is that the source files that attempt to read the files live in a src/ subdirectory. My understanding though is that I should be able to reference the files relative to the project, not the actual source files themselves. Just in case, I tried "../res/default.vert" to no avail.

Any help is appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: You use relative paths. Could it be that the current working directory is not what you think it is, and the file really is not found?

Comment: Is there a reason relative paths would work in one project but not in another? The current structure is: Root/src, Root/res and the cpp file with the fileToBuffer is under Root/src/OSUtils.cpp and the shader files are in Root/res/default.vert etc.

Comment: It doesn't really matter where the source files are. What matters is how the executable is run. Rather then guessing, I suggest you print the result of [`getcwd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getcwd.3.html) call

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in fact related to the working directory. There's a custom setting under the schemes that lets you set a custom working dir. Obviously not really suitable for distribution, but that explains the discrepancy. Thanks for the help!